# How to retrieve 'id' column from entering other fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Here is my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($submit)){
    require 'db/connect.php';
    $sql = "SELECT ID from users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $entered_user = mysql_query($sql);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($entered_user);

    $errors = array();

    if( $num_rows != 1 )
    {
        $errors[] = '-Account does not exist ';
    }
    elseif( $num_rows == 1 )
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($entered_user)){
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
        $errors[] = 'ID NUMBER --> '.$id;
    }
}
?>
```

My question: How can I store the id number of a particular account into a variable? I cannot produce an id number and the only output I receive when entering an existing account is 'ID NUMBER -->' without the following id.

DB column names: id, username, password.
$username, $password and $submit are the post variables.

Comment: is it `ID` or `id` ??? because they are not the same

Comment: Execute `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and see what happens.

Comment: You could set the id to auto increment in your database

Comment: guys, column id is auto incremented. I want to retrieve that id column number that corresponds with the other column data and store it in a variable

Comment: then why are you asking in the query for `ID`

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I was using capitals the entire time... was pulling hair out over this one! Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to close a question?

Comment: Warnining, deprecated code alert.

Comment: Would use PDO but using web hosting that is not updated :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the name of the column in your query:

```
 $sql = "SELECT ID as id from users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
```

or when you try to fetch it:

```
$id = $row['ID'];
```

Also please don't store passwords as plaintext. Read up on how to handle [passwords in PHP](http://php.net/password).

Comment: If you learn, then also learn how to properly hash passwords.

Comment: Recently learned password_hash() and password_verify(), however is there a way to close a question on StackOverflow after being satisfied with an answer?